# DBFlow model without primary key

Tags: android, orm

When i try write model without primary key i get

`Error:Table SCHEDULE_ITEM needs to define at least one primary key`

Is posible write dbflow model without @PrimaryKey field ?

**Model:**

```
@Table(databaseName = AppDatabase.NAME, tableName = "SCHEDULE_ITEM")
public class ScheduleItem extends BaseModel implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "ITEM_TYPE")
    private Integer itemType;
    @Column(name = "INTERNAL_ID")
    private String internalId;
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private String date;
    @Column(name = "TIME")
    private String time;

    //geters and seters
}
```

Comment: where is your code? post your code first

Comment: could you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, I got weird errors recently as below, said it couldn't find those "$Table" classes, but actually they had been built and in there.

I commented and uncommented every new java files. And eventually I found that's because there is no "@PrimaryKey" in one model class of DBFlow.

So, you have to define the bloody **"@PrimaryKey"** for your DBFlow model classes( and don't forget to **extends BaseModel** as well).

Another important but very hard to find thing is, don't define same name filed for @Table annotation in two model classes. For my example, I gave *@Table(name = "ClientMode"* in my new class "ClientEntity", but in the existing ClientMode class, there has already been a line of *@Table(name = "ClientMode"*.

Regarding the above issues, the compliler can't give you any useful hint or error information.

PS: DBFlow Version 3.0.0-beta

```
/Users/XXX/code_projects/###/src/main/java/com/XXXXX.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import com.XXX.databasemodel.XXX$Table
```